# Run init.d script during boot

Tags: init, runlevel

I need to do something apparently quite simple: run a script on a Debian 8.2  machine during boot (or during shutdown, both of them are fine).

The script just moves and renames some files, so the only thing it needs is that the root filesystem is mounted. However, it **must** run before networking is started.

I tried putting the script in `/etc/init.d`, and symlinking it to `/etc/rc3.d/S12-a-scriptname.sh` so that it runs just before networking. However... it just doesn't run.

I also tried symlinking it automatically using `update-rc.d`, but it still doesn't work. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: You need to [edit] the question and tell the world _what version_ of Debian Linux this is.  It's important.

Answer (score 0):

Networking in Debian starts at run level S, which comes before run level 3.

Sources, for reference:

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_the_meaning_of_the_runlevel

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_network_interface_initialization

Comment: As mentioned in a comment to the question, the version of Debian is important.  The above is no longer actually the case for Debian version 8, for example, as is pointed out (albeit perhaps not emphatically enough) earlier in that very same manual.